# how to fix jquery calendar on IE browser?

Tags: jquery

anyone of you who is experiencing the same problem as mine, wherein, the JQuery calendar keep on popping out even after the user selected a date already via IE. what's the solution to fix this ?..because in other browsers such as FF,Chrome, Safari ,the jquery calendar work.
here's the simple code i use in all my date input field

```
$(function(){
  $('#datepicker').datepicker({changeYear: true,changeMonth: true,yearRange:'1940:2011',defaultDate:+7});
})
```

Comment: Haven't experience something like this at all. Can you post your code here to check?

Answer (score 0):

jQuery datepicker adds a new attribute to the DOM element in IE. if you try to add a new DOM element dynamically copying from an existing element the datepicker will not work in IE as the newly added DOM element refers to the old jQuery attribute. One way to fix this is to delete the attribute and then instantiate the datepicker class on the element. See the following code for the fix.

```
 //newDiv is the new added dom element with innerHTML
 jQuery("#newDiv").find(".datePicker").each(function() {
//removing jquery added attribute as this is causing the dynamically
// added DOM elem referring old DOM element from it is copied.
if (jQuery.browser.msie) {
    var jqaddedattr;
    jQuery(this.attributes).each(function() {
        if (this.name.search(/jQuery/) != -1) {
            jqaddedattr = this;
        }
    });
    if (jqaddedattr) {
        jQuery(this).removeAttr(jqaddedattr.name);
    }
}
jQuery(this).datepicker({yearRange: '-100:+10',    changeFirstDay:false}).val("").trigger('change');
})
```